# Remove a specific number of rows before and after NaN value in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns (date and value), in the value column there are NaN values, I want to remove 3 values before and after each NaN value.
Below is my example data frame.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Test.dat", skiprows=0,  sep='\t', parse_dates = ['Date'])
```

```
Date Value
2019-10-17 22:15    NaN
2019-10-17 22:20    100
2019-10-17 22:25    100
2019-10-17 22:30    100
2019-10-17 22:35    36.46
2019-10-17 22:40    36.51
2019-10-17 22:45    36.58
2019-10-17 22:50    36.75
2019-10-17 22:55    100
2019-10-17 23:00    100
2019-10-17 23:05    100
2019-10-17 23:10    NaN
```

Basically, I'd like to get a data frame such as the following.

```
Date Value
2019-10-17 22:15    NaN
2019-10-17 22:20    NaN
2019-10-17 22:25    NaN
2019-10-17 22:30    NaN
2019-10-17 22:35    36.46
2019-10-17 22:40    36.51
2019-10-17 22:45    36.58
2019-10-17 22:50    36.75
2019-10-17 22:55    NaN
2019-10-17 23:00    NaN
2019-10-17 23:05    NaN
2019-10-17 23:10    NaN
```

Comment: I guess it was downvoted because folks here don't like when data is posted as images. Showing your attempts (and generally, putting more effort into writing a quality question) would also attract more attention and increase chances of getting a proper answer.

Comment: OK, noted, thank you. I will upload the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other approach to solve this.

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].shift(-3).isnull(), np.nan, df['Value'])
```

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Value'].shift(3).isnull(), np.nan, df['Value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the index of NaN and all the indices that's at most 3 away from NaN:

```
idx_set_to_nan = list(set([y for x in [list(range(x-3,x+4)) for x in df[df.Value.isna()].index.tolist()] for y in x if y >= 0 and y < df.shape[0]]))

>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

It's a long expression, but basically it's doing the following:

1. `df[df.Value.isna()].index.tolist()` to get the index of NaN in `Value` column.
2. `[list(range(x-3,x+4)) for x in df[df.Value.isna()].index.tolist()]` to get max-3 distance indices around NaN indices.
3. `[y for x in [list(range(x-3,x+4)) for x in df[df.Value.isna()].index.tolist()] for y in x if y >= 0 and y < df.shape[0]]` to crop and get rid of indices that's out of data frame index range (`<0` or `>=df.shape[0]`).
4. `list(set( ... ))` to get unique values of the result of #3.

Then you set those index of Value in df to NaN:

```
df.loc[idx_set_to_nan, "Value"] = None
```